# Use dir /D command without square brackets as output

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I would like to perform a filtered dir command and store the output into a file.
I only need all found files/directories, but no square brackets.

I would like to find all folders that contain a specific wording in its name.

```
dir %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages /D | find "com.testfolder" > output.txt
```

A much simpler example:

```
dir %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages /D
```

Actual result:

```
[com.testfolder.First]
[com.testfolder.Second]
```

Expected result:

```
com.testfolder.First
com.testfolder.Second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the `/b` parameter?

```
dir /b %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\*com.testfolder* > output.txt
```

E.g. on my computer

```
dir /b %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\*office*
```

displays:

```
Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```